# Width and height of a saved Netlogo applet?

Tags: applet, netlogo

Given (x_top_left, y_top_left) and (x_low_right, y_low_right) in the Netlogo source, what should the width and height of the saved Netlogo applet be?

### Background

I have a ton of authentic Netlogo files, prepared for courses and demos.  Using Perl or Ruby, I'd like to export them in batch as an applet in different files, possibly related by a table of contents in a left frame or so.  Much like  "save as applet", but then in batch, to different HTML files.

All is trivial to do were it not that I got stuck in finding out which applet dimensions I am supposed to use in writing

```
<applet code="org.nlogo.lite.Applet" archive="NetLogoLite.jar"
       width="???" height="???">
<param name="DefaultModel" value="netlogofile.nlogo">
</applet>
```

Notice the ???.  I searched for other Netlogo file parsers and encountered https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Model-file-format, which is not specific enough and https://github.com/rikblok/dokuwiki-plugin-netlogo/blob/master/syntax/applet.php which is a parser but yields results which appear useless to me.  (I got it running but it seems to parse the Netlogo source wrongly.)

### Netlogo file format

I figured out that the Netlogo file format is like the following (comments after semicolon)

```
@#$#@#$#@
GRAPHICS-WINDOW
210 ; x-coord of upper left corner
10  ; y-coord of upper left corner
544 ; x-coord of lower right corner?
215 ; y-coord of lower right corner?
-1
-1
2.77 ; patch size
1
10 ; font size
1
1
1
0
1
0 ; world-wrap
1 world-wrap
-45 ; min-pxcor
71 ; max-pcor
-33 ; min-pycor
29 max-pycor
0
0
1 ; show tick counter
ticks ; tick counter label
```

To get a feeling for the logics I parsed a few saved applets and got the following results:

```
(x_top_left, y_top_left) = (210, 10).
(x_low_right, y_low_right) = (649, 470).
Netlogo saves applet with width x height: 794 x 480.

(x_top_left, y_top_left) = (96, 10).
(x_low_right, y_low_right) = (535, 470).
Netlogo saves applet with width x height: 629 x 480.

(x_top_left, y_top_left) = (96, 10).
(x_low_right, y_low_right) = (483, 340).
Netlogo saves applet with width x height: 575 x 350.

(x_top_left, y_top_left) = (96, 10).
(x_low_right, y_low_right) = (396, 271).
Netlogo saves applet with width x height: 690 x 300.
```

From these data I tried to discover a pattern in these numbers but the relation between them frankly is beyond me.

My question is: given (x_top_left, y_top_left) and (x_low_right, y_low_right) in the Netlogo source, what should the width and height of the saved Netlogo applet be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to look at the dimensions of all of the widgets in the Interface tab, compute the bounding box for all of them together, and then add some slop.

I know of two implementations of this calculation, both pretty craptastic.

One is the one in NetLogo itself.  It's here, split across two files:

- https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/blob/22bd1361ab7ecc1c186448ebb2a77ba993b8fb8b/src/main/org/nlogo/app/AppletSaver.scala#L23-L47
- https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/blob/22bd1361ab7ecc1c186448ebb2a77ba993b8fb8b/src/main/org/nlogo/app/WidgetPanel.java#L112-L145

The other is on the Perl scripts (Perl? yeah, it was 2002, barely been touched since) on the NetLogo website that serve up the applet versions of the Models Library models. Those scripts are in a private repo, but I made a gist of the relevant section:

- https://gist.github.com/SethTisue/98a1b92db00dcd6a4f79

I haven't looked at this stuff in donkey's years, but if you have questions about it, it's possible my memory could be jogged.

Comment: I rolled my own script, partly because I did not understand the exact bounding box calculation magic.  What I did is: compute the Min and Max of all the _x_ and _y_ coordinates of the GRAPHICS-WINDOW BUTTON SLIDER SWITCH CHOOSER INPUTBOX MONITOR PLOT OUTPUT TEXTBOX CHOICE widgets, and subtract the max from the min for each coordinate.  Pretty straightforward, indeed.  Still, my answers deviate from what Netlogo itself computes when it saves applets.  I understand some slack is added due to overlap due to browser peculiarities.  But also the slack added varies.  What should I add as slack?

Comment: Re: the bounding box, yeah, that's exactly what the code I linked to does. As for slack, I don't think there is any definitive answer to the how-much question. The amount of slack added in the code I've linked to was purely the product of trial and error over the years: if we noticed a problem or someone complained, we added a few more pixels of slack until it went away.

Comment: Umm... yes, but the slack added per save varies.  A lot.  If the calculations on my side are correct it seems like magic is going on instead of adding constant slack at each save.  To eliminate the magic I peeked at code fragments you mentioned, but these fragments read their dimensions from the widget objects themselves. I have another look and make the best of it.  Like you said, it is indeed questionable to spend time on Netlogo applets while work on Tortoise in under way.  Since I want to publish my proggies in the Spring, I am more or less forced to use the applet solution---which is OK.

Comment: I'm sure that the widget dimensions in the objects and the widgets dimensions written to the file are identical, so that's a difference that doesn't matter.